# avoid skipping lines after missing values

Tags: input, sas, file-io

while input procedure with 7 variables like this

```
Infile "C:\Users\Gila\Desktop\StatOrdinL2020\artiste1.txt" dlm="*" DSD;
LENGTH Artiste $ 25 titre $30;
Input
Artiste $ Titre  Prix  Deces  Hauteur   Largeur  Medium;
```

this database

```
Abatucci Pierre*Derniers rayons*1200*1*55*84*5
Abatucci Pierre*L'entrée au château*1000*1*75*91
Agneessens Edouard*Jeune femme*6000*1*40*32*5
```

in the second lines there are only 6 variables and the third one will be skipped but it should not

Comment: You can encourage people to answer your question by going back to your previous questions and accepting the answer that worked best for you. (Click on the check mark.)

Answer (score 2):

You can tell SAS to assign missing values when variables are missing by adding `missover` to your `infile` statement:

```
Infile "C:\temp\artiste1.txt" dlm="*" DSD missover;
```